# How to store an Image of type PIL.Jpegimageplugin.Jpegimagefile into Odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, openpyxl

I'm retrieving data from excel and one of the column is bunch of images mostly jpeg, I'm using openpyxl and openpyxl_image_loader to read excel and retrieve data

This is how I'm reading my data

```py
def get_data_from_excel(file):
    data = defaultdict(list)  
    try:  
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(base64.b64decode(file)))  
        ws = wb.active  
        image_loader = SheetImageLoader(ws)  
        # first row will be keys in dict  
        keys = [cell.value for cell in ws[1]]  
        i = 0
        for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=ws.max_column, max_row=ws.max_row):  
            temp = {}  
            for key, cell in zip(keys, row):  
                if key == 'Photo':  
                    try:  
                        image = image_loader.get(cell.coordinate)  
                          
                        temp[key] = base64.b64decode(image.tobytes())
                        continue  
                    except Exception as e:  
                        print(e)  
                        temp[key] = False  
                        break           
                temp[key] = cell.value  
            data[i].append(temp)
            i+=1  
            
      
    except Exception as e:  
        raise ValidationError(_('Please upload a valid Excel file! ', e))  
    finally:  
        return data
```

trying to set the data into a field after getting the model through id

```py
def set_photo(self, model, photo):  
    try:  
        model.image_1920 = photo   
    except Exception as e:  
        print(f'Error while setting photo for model {model}, error: {e}')
```

the error I get

> This file could not be decoded as an image file. Please try with a different file.

I tried to use Pillow `open()` function and i get this exception

> UnidentifiedImageError('cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f3ddcb0b2c0>')

More details about the image attributes

[image: image_details]

Using guess_mimetype

```py
print(guess_mimetype(base64.b64decode(image.tobytes())))
```

OUTPUTs

> application/octet-stream

I'd appreciate any help or explanation, thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it's only me, but I don't see any lines in this code that would attempt to load an image.

Comment: @tevemadar im using `SheetImageLoader` from `openpyxl_image_loader` to load the sheet/images

Comment: On the face of it the code looks like it would run OK, What line does the error occur on? You should always provide the complete traceback so these details are clear to anybody looking at your issue.

Comment: @moken the error occur when i set the image `set_photo()` it tries to set the image then jumps to the exception

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work, I had to change how I'm converting `JpegImageFile` to base64

```py
image = image_loader.get(cell.coordinate)
buffer = BytesIO()
image.save(buffer, format=image.format)
image_bytes = buffer.getvalue()
image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_bytes)
```

final code

```py
def get_data_from_excel(file):
    data = defaultdict(list)  
    try:  
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(base64.b64decode(file)))  
        ws = wb.active  
        image_loader = SheetImageLoader(ws)  
        # first row will be keys in dict  
        keys = [cell.value for cell in ws[1]]  
        i = 0
        for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=ws.max_column, max_row=ws.max_row):  
            temp = {}  
            for key, cell in zip(keys, row):  
                if key == 'Photo':  
                    try:  
                        image = image_loader.get(cell.coordinate)  
                        buffer = BytesIO()  
                        image.save(buffer, format=image.format)  
                        image_bytes = buffer.getvalue()  
                        image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_bytes)  
                          
                        temp[key] = image_base64
                        continue  
                    except Exception as e:  
                        print(e)  
                        temp[key] = False  
                        break           
                temp[key] = cell.value  
            data[i].append(temp)
            i+=1  
            
      
    except Exception as e:  
        raise ValidationError(_('Please upload a valid Excel file! ', e))  
    finally:  
        return data
```

not sure if this gonna help anyone but I'm leaving my answer here just in case